# Variable losing its value in Cocos2d-x for Blackberry

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2d-x on Blackberry Playbook. I'm trying to center a jpeg on the screen, but the variable I use to get the size of the screen somehow ends up being 0. Even though I can confirm that it is non-zero before the jpeg is loaded and positioned. The code in my init function is below:

```
bool MyScene::init() {

    if ( !CCLayer::init() ) {
        return false;
    }

    CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    bg = CCSprite::create("2.jpg");
    bg->setPosition(ccp( size.width/2 , size.height/2 ));
    this->addChild(bg); 

    fg = CCSprite::create("hud2.png");
    fg->setPosition(ccp( size.width/2 , 25 ));
    this->addChild(fg);

    fg2 = CCSprite::create("hud.png");
    fg2->setPosition(ccp( size.width/2 , size.height - 30 ));
    this->addChild(fg2);

    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "size is " << (size.width/2) << "and " (size.height/2);
    std::string outtext = stream.str();

    label = CCLabelTTF::create(outtext.c_str(), "DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 25, CCSizeMake(size.width, 25), kCCTextAlignmentCenter);
    label->setPosition(ccp( size.width/2 , 28 ));
    this->addChild(label);
}
```

If I run that, the label will print out that size is 0 and the jpeg is in the lower left corner instead of centered in the middle. However, if I load a png instead of the jpeg, everything works fine. To further confuse me, if I move the code that fills the string with the values of 'size' to right under the code that sets 'size', everything works fine. If I put that code anywhere else, or take it out completely, 'size' (presumably) goes back to 0 and the jpeg doesn't get centered. This problem only happens on Blackberry, but it seems like 'size' is getting set correctly so I don't know that it is a cocos2d-x bug. Could there be some compiler kookiness messing things up or just some really simple error I'm missing that other compilers are more forgiving for?

To confuse things even further, I have another app where the background is setup in a separate function called initBackground that is called from the main init function. In that app, the background gets positioned wrong even if I manually set the position to the middle of the screen. The height is right, but if I set the x position to 160 it behaves just as though I'd set it to 0 and only half of the image shows.

I don't mind digging into the cocos2d-x code, but any hints on where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but I will try to give some suggestions in case someone else has a similar issue. From your question, I imagine that one variable that could mess around with the positioning of your images is the anchorpoint value. Maybe for some reason your anchorpoint is set to a different value that (0.5,0.5) which is the centre of your image.

> The anchorPoint has a value range of 0.0 to 1.0 (0% to 100%). If the anchorPoint is 0.5x0.5 (the default for nodes with textures) then the texture is centered on the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 0x0, then the texture's lower left corner aligns with the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 1x1 then the texture's upper right corner aligns with the node's position. This makes anchorPoint most popular when it comes to left, right, top or bottom align nodes. It is most often used to align text labels or to align screen elements with screen borders.

You may learn more about the anchorPoint here http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/How+The+Anchor+Point+Works+And+What+To+Use+It+For

About your variable being reset to zero, I imagine there might be some issues with these lines .. 
`std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "size is " << (size.width/2) << "and " (size.height/2);
    std::string outtext = stream.str();`

> Blockquote

Im more of a java programmer, but I imagine there should be a way to directly add the vale of size.width to your label and print it out.

Hope the anchorPoint suggestion helps.